# PHP: How to avoid defined() while checking if constant exists?

Tags: php, performance

Many experienced developer knows that function `defined()` is arround 19 times slower than any other checks.

I got in the problem where I need to have loop with over 5000 records and 7 `defined()` checks in the sequence and that slowdown complete project.

Changing a way of project work or chunking is not possible in this case. Is there some good solution or idea how to avoid `defined()` function?

Comment: It's hard to say without further context. What do you use the constants for? What part of your flow is suitable for changes? But it sounds weird. My fairly low-end computer runs a loop of 7 * 5000 define checks in 26 milliseconds after a cold run (13 seconds on next executions). Is that really the level of optimisation you need to accomplish?

Comment: Evaluate `defined()` once and store the result to a variable. In the loop, check the variable.

Answer (score 2):

I test something like :

`if(!defined('TEST')) continue;`

and

`if(!@TEST) continue;`

and

`if(NULL === @constant('TEST')) continue;`

My measures on the PHP 7.1 is that :

`if(!@TEST) continue;` is faster than `if(NULL === @constant('TEST')) continue;`

but both is slower than `if(!defined('TEST')) continue;`

It seams that we not have faster solution yet and `defined()` is still the faster way to check if constant exists.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using

```
constant ( string $name ) : mixed
```

> Returns the value of the constant, or NULL if the constant is not
>   defined.

Given that in php null == false

```
if (defined($name))
```

and

```
if (constant($name))
```

are almost identical
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php

Comment: Is it *faster* though…?

Comment: @deceze That's why I phrased it as "Did you try". Because I couldn't find information about their execution speeds.

Comment: Hm... I not think about it. `if(NUII !== constant('SOMETHING'))` can be some solution but need to test. Will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @EinārsBistrovs An E_WARNING level error is generated if the constant is not defined and also is double slower than `define()`